# Is it possible to reference a different column in the same table?

Tags: sql, create-table, hierarchical

If a blog has a 'categories' table such as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT,
  count INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

And if the parent_id field is intended to refer to the 'id' field of the categories table, then how could I add a constraint that would ensure that values inserted into parent_id references the id field?

I simply want to make sure that only category id values that exist can be used as a parent of a newly inserted category.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can reference a column in the same table.

But that column should be nullable otherwise you can't insert the first record.

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INTEGER NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT,
  count INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

Note that after the REFERENCES keyword the table name is not optional, so you must specify it even if you are referencing a column in the same table. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
reference_definition:
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
      [MATCH FULL | MATCH PARTIAL | MATCH SIMPLE]
      [ON DELETE reference_option]
      [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f84d6/1)

Comment: So does that mean I should do something like: parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES (id) ?

Comment: @JimJohnson: You need to specify the table name.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a normal foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT FK_categories_Parent_ID 
REFERENCES categories (ID)
```

However Parent_ID should be nullable as you'll never be able to insert a record

Comment: I never knew that foreign keys could also be columns in the same table >.<

Comment: Could I default parent_id to 0 by any chance?

Comment: @JimJohnson: Do you have a row 0 in your table? If not, your foreign key constraint will fail if you try to add a row with parent_id = 0. But you can use NULL instead.

Comment: @Mark Byers I'll just use NULL instead :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link. It has how you can do it Oracle database.

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/data_samples/hierarchic_yahoo.html

Thanks